# Matlab optimiziation where objective is implicitly given by a fixed point equation

Tags: matlab, optimization, fixed-point-iteration

I have the following problem:

max CEQ(w) s.t. w in (0,1) and I don't know anything about CEQ(w) except that is given by a fixed point equation of the form CEQ(w) = F(CEQ(w)). If I fix a w, I can solve the fixed point equation using the fzero function and obtain a value for CEQ. If I choose a different w, I get another value for CEQ. Thus, I could loop over all possible values of w and then choose the one that gives the highest CEQ. This seems bad programming though and I was wondering whether I can do this more efficient in MATLAB: I want to model the solution to my fixed point equation as a function of w but I don't know how to implement it.

To be more precise, here is a sample code:

```
clear all
clc

NoDraws = 1000000;
T_hat = 12;
mu = 0.0058;
variance = 0.0017;
rf = 0.0036;
sim_returns(:,T_hat/12) = T_hat*mu + sqrt(T_hat*variance)*randn(NoDraws,1);

A = 5;
kappa=1;
l=0;
theta = 1 - l*(kappa^(1-A) - 1) *(kappa>1);

CEQ_DA_0 = 1.1; 
CEQ_opt = -1000;
w_opt = 0;

W_T = @(w) (1-w)*exp(rf*T_hat) + w*exp(rf*T_hat + sim_returns(:,T_hat/12));
for w=0.01:0.01:0.99
    W=W_T(w);
    fp = @(CEQ) theta*CEQ^(1-A)/(1-A) - mean( W.^(1-A)/(1-A)) + l*mean( ((kappa*CEQ)^(1-A)/(1-A) - W.^(1-A)/(1-A)) .* (W < kappa*CEQ)); 
    CEQ_DA = fzero(fp,CEQ_DA_0);
    if CEQ_DA > CEQ_opt
        CEQ_opt = CEQ_DA;
        w_opt = w;
    end
end
```

That is, in the loop, I fix a w, solve the fixed point equation and store the value for CEQ. If some other w gives a bigger value for CEQ, the current optimal w gets replaced by that new w. what I would like to have (instead of the loop part) is something like this:

```
fp = @(CEQ,w) theta*CEQ^(1-A)/(1-A) - mean( W_T(w).^(1-A)/(1-A)) + l*mean( ((kappa*CEQ)^(1-A)/(1-A) - W_T(w).^(1-A)/(1-A)) .* (W_T(w) < kappa*CEQ)); 
CEQ_DA = @(w) fzero(fp,CEQ_DA_0);
[w_opt, fval]=fminbnd(CEQ_DA,0,1);
```

Comment: That looks like a good approach.  Where are you having trouble?

Comment: my suggestion doesn't work. It seems like the fzero function does not want to be treated as a function of w. For example if I type CEQ_DA(0.5), I get the error for the fzero command:  Not enough input arguments. (apparently because it still needs two inputs). The looping stuff takes very long and is not very precise..

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution is very close.  In words, you're defining `fp` as a function of two arguments, and would like CEQ_DA to be a function of `w`, which solves `fp` for CEQ, with that given `w`.  The only issue is that `fzero` doesn't know which parameter of fp to solve over, because it can't match anonymous function parameters and fp parameters by name.

The answer is yet one more anonymous function inside the fzero, to turn `fp(CEP,w)` into `fp_w(CEP)`, which will be solveable for CEQ

```
CEQ_DA = @(w) fzero(@(CEQ) fp(CEQ, w),CEQ_DA_0);
```